# win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) returns -32768 instead of 1 when pressed

Tags: python, winapi, pyautogui

I tried using win32api today, and it said only that GetAsyncKeyState would return 1 if the key is pressed or 0 if not.

But when i ran it with the left mouse button it returned -32768?
I found this out by printing said command.
It doesnt break anything because i can just say if leftmouse==-32768 but it still got me a bit confused. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) says:

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down.

The most significant bit in a signed integer is the sign bit. So you can read this as stating that the function returns a negative value if the key is down.

You should not test `== -32768`, rather test `< 0`.

Comment: No. You need to test for the most significant bit, as the documentation says. Other bits may be set, the value is non-zero, but the most significant bit is clear. As stated in my answer, test `< 0`.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) states:

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to `GetAsyncKeyState`.

-32768 is 0x8000, which means the high bit is set.  That matches your description of "i ran it with the left mouse button". You held the button down, and that is what `GetAsyncKeyState()` reported. Whatever you are reading that says "GetAsyncKeyState would return 1 if the key is pressed or 0 if not" is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but i'd like to know what "If the most significant bit is set" means? Is it something that i dont have to worry about, or is it something i should know? Because i'm not sure what "bit" is referring to, or actually, anything of that sentence.
@David Heffernan

Comment: @Leno22ß6 yes, it helps if you have at least a basic understanding of what "bits" are, and how "bytes" are comprised of "bits", and how "bits" and "bytes" are used in data types, like integers